# Android. Displaying Large String ArrayList in GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, arraylist

I have a problem when displaying a large ArrayList in a GridView.

The ArrayList is populated by a range of single characters, where the range is entered by the user.

The GridView displays each value in the ArrayList and, when an item is pressed, the string is inserted into an EditText.

All the above works. The problem arises when I press in the EditText.

When the ArrayList contains a large number of entries ( > 1000), there is a noticeable pause when the EditText is pressed and the GridView loses focus. This pause increases depending of the number of ArrayList entries.

The ArrayList is created as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = startValue; i <= endValue; i++) {
        list.add(new String(Character.toChars(i)));
    }

    gridView.setAdapter(new CharAdapter(mActivity, list));
```

The adapter is as follows:

```
public class CharAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public CharAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.chars_gridview_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.charTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String chr = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.charTextView.setText(chr);

        return convertView;
    }
}

static class ViewHolderItem {

    TextView charTextView;
}
```

Any ideas what is happening and how to stop it?

Comment: It's probably not very helpful for the user to be presented with 1000+ results. Perhaps limit to a more manageable number and have an indication there are more.

Answer (score 0):

It's a heavy operation which happens on the main thread. While it is running, it locks the main thread, hence your visual issues.

You would need to move your code:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = startValue; i <= endValue; i++) {
    list.add(new String(Character.toChars(i)));
}
```

into a separate runnable.

If this does not help too much, then set it into an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instance and set your adapter in [AsyncTask.onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result))

Comment: That section of the code does not seem to be the problem. The ArrayList if filled and the values displayed in the GridView with very little pause. The problem is when I move focus from the GridView to the TextEdit.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to use an AsyncTask anyway. I'm new to Java and Android and hadn't heard of this before.